# Python datetime and json format

Tags: python, json, python-requests, datetime-format

I am programming against a REST API. I need to send in the body of a POST some parameters:

```
{
  "contract": {
    "name": "string",
    "beginDate": "2021-01-29T14:49:46.778Z",
    "endDate": "2021-01-29T14:49:46.778Z"
  },
  "pageSize": 0,
  "webhookEndpoint": "string"
}
```

My problem is that I am struggling to convert my `datetime` abstraction in Python to this weird format in JSON.

Here's what I've already tried:

```
from requests import post
payload = {
    "contract":{
        "name": fund,
        "startDate": datetime.now() - timedelta(1),
        "endDate": datetime.now()}
    "pageSize": 300
}
headers = {
    "X-SecureConnect-Token": "12345",
    "Content-Type": "application/json-patch+json", #copied from swagger
    "Accept": "text/plain" #copied from swagger, everything works there
}
r = post("https://theapi.com/endpoint",headers=headers,data=payload) #Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable
```

I already tried to use the `json` module. I don't know how this abstraction of the API works (apparently is what happens when you convert a JavaScript date to a string, and I would enjoy very much to not have the bourdein of writing the parser).

Answer (score 1):

They're not JSON serializable because your passing Python datetime objects to the JSON as opposed to the string representation of the time.

You can demonstrate this in an interpreter, by doing the following:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime, timedelta

>>> type(datetime.now() - timedelta(1))
<class 'datetime.datetime'>

>>> type(datetime.isoformat(datetime.now() - timedelta(1)))
<class 'str'>
```

As you can see, the thing you're passing is of class datetime.datetime. If you wrap that with datetime.isoformat, you'll get out a a string representation in almost the format you want. You then just need to truncate it and add your Zulu letter to the end.

Try something like this:

```
from requests import post
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


payload = {
    "contract":{
        "name": fund,
        "startDate": datetime.isoformat(datetime.now() - timedelta(1))[:-3]+'Z',
        "endDate": datetime.isoformat(datetime.now())[:-3]+'Z'},
    "pageSize": 300
}
headers = {
    "X-SecureConnect-Token": "12345",
    "Content-Type": "application/json-patch+json", #copied from swagger
    "Accept": "text/plain" #copied from swagger, everything works there
}
r = post("https://theapi.com/endpoint",headers=headers,data=payload) #Object of type datetime is not JSON serializable
```